# read and display data from text file from database query in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pydev

I am newbie in python and i am stuck with kind of database engine problem in python

I have text file database table(person.text) with a delimiter(|) separated in python. For example

```
sue|45|Happy Lane|456-3245
John|43|67 Drury Lane|897-3456
Mark|21|Stuffy Street|345-7896
```

Now i want a functionality that take queries from user and fetch data from this text file and display. queries can be select,update (with or without where clause).

For example If user give input as "select name from person  " then output would be

```
sue
John
Mark
```

I am confuse which data structure should i use ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of data = f.split("|") it should be data = line.split("|").

I need to write query in user input and then it must be interpreted by code. If i use above solution then how can a match my SQL queries with dictionary ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey you should use the comment section. You can then search through the dictionary with a for loop. Editing my below answer to include that now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your current text based database you would probably need to parse it manually then store it do a local dictionary (defaultdict makes it easy) to allow for keyword searching. I added a numeric primary key to help store the data in a keyword-searchable form

```
from collections import defaultdict

person = defaultdict(lambda: dict())

with open("path/to/person.txt", "r") as f:
    primary_key = 0
    for line in f:
        data = line.split("|")
        person[primary_key]["name"] = data[0]
        person[primary_key]["age"] = data[1]
        person[primary_key]["address"] = data[2]
        person[primary_key]["pnum"] = data[3]
        primary_key += 1
```

Then you would have a local dictionary named `person` that can be searched through using keywords inputted by the end user.

Searching:

```
query = "select name from person"

query_items = query.split(" ")

if query_items[0] == "select":
    table = eval(query_items[3])
    for value in table.values():
        print(value[query_items[1]])
```